# Recommended Scientific Calculator for Android

Tags: android, calculator

There's a lot of calculator apps out there, but I'm looking for something that

- works offline
- is ad-free
- supports bracketing (i.e. `3*(2+5)`)
- has the usual functionality like exponation `x^y`
- has a few constants, mainly π and e
- has at least one logarithm
- nice to have:

  - trigonometry
  - complex analysis
  - plotting
  - is free

**EDIT**:

I'm about to extract the firmware of my TI-89+ and use that in graph 89, which is free as in beer and freedom, but emulating a "buttoned" calculator seems like a mediocre solution.

Comment: So by looking for something "ad free" I'm guessing you're ok with paying for this app?

Comment: @New-To-IT in practice, yes. Not about to spend USD 10 or more, but if it's a fine calculator, then spending USD 3 doesn't sound bad.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at my list of [Pocket calculators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_accessories#group_127). The top-one might match your needs for just ~EUR 1.25 (only required permission: "vibrate"). Don't know about the feature-matches – but you could use the [app search](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/search) to limit the list to "calculators not requiring Internet" :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [RealCalc Plus](http://www.quartic-software.co.uk/).

Here's the [direct link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalcPlus) to the app page on Google Play, and a brief description:

> RealCalc is designed to look and operate exactly like a real hand-held
>   calculator. It has all the standard scientific functions plus history,
>   memories, unit conversions and constants. You can choose from a number
>   of display styles and formats. It also supports binary, octal and
>   hexadecimal calculations and has an optional RPN mode. RealCalc is
>   easy to use, but has full help included in the app.
>
> The pro version RealCalc Plus has lots of extra features including
>   fractions, degrees/minutes/seconds, customizable conversions and
>   constants, landscape mode, a home-screen widget, a 12-digit display
>   and greater internal precision.

It matches all your must-have requirements and it's well within your 10 USD budget. It's a pretty popular app, it has good reviews and it's updated regularly.

Here are a couple of screenshots from the website:

[image: RealCalc Plus 1]

[image: RealCalc Plus 2]

The full list of features and more screenshots are available if you follow the links provided above.

Comment: I'm giving this an upvote, but it's not really what I'm looking for; it's really just an emulation of the user interface of a classical calculator, and at this, my emulated TI-89+ is really more impressive.